# Is there any support in Cycle or Eevee for volumetric data rendering on a non-uniform grid?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I have some volumetric data (on a non-uniform grid) in files and I would like to be able to use blender to make volume rendering of them.

The difficulty here is that the data is actually sampled on an octree with a fairly large depth, which prevents any reprojection on a uniform coarse grid.

Is there any support in Cycle or Eevee for volume on non-uniform grid?

Comment: Just updated. Is that better?